# How do I write German language on a web page?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have to build a web page in German language. When I use some characters like ü (note the dots above the letter), it shows up like a question mark or black sign in the browser.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Which program are you using to create the webpage? And what encodings does it support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the wrong encoding. Make sure that you're saving your web site as UTF-8 and put the following in your `HTML` `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use UTF-8 all throughout your project or instead of writing the `ü` you could write the htmlentity `&uuml;` (also analogue: `&auml; &Auml;` etc ... And `&szlig;`for `ß`

PS: As a German myself... Our language is called Germ ***a*** n :)

Comment: You could certainly use legacy Latin-1 or Latin-9 encoding, too, as long as your editor, the web server, and any charset tag in the file all agree.

Comment: Yeah, good point. But when starting now, go with UTF-8 so you have all those Russian, Chinese and Japanese people covered, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf8 encoding by adding the following header to your webpage:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Also make sure your files are saved as utf8, this depends on your editor